# how to get a count of div's that contain certain text, when the search value is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, contains

I want to allow the user to enter in a search string and I want to return the count of how many times that search item is found.  I can get this to work if I hard code the search value into the 'contains' method, but as soon as I store the search value into a variable it no longer works.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="myTest">this</div>
<div class="myTest">this</div>
<div class="myTest">that</div>
<div class="myTest">that</div>
<div class="myTest">this</div>
<div id="howMany"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
$(function() {
    var myVal= "that";  
    var existingList = $("div:contains(myVal) + .myTest").length;
    $("div[id*='howMany']").html(existingList);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few errors in your code :

- `+` in jQuery selectors [doesn't do](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) what you think it does
- you're including the string `myVal` and not the value of `myVal` in the selector
- use `#` to look for an element with a given id

You could search using

```
var existingList = $('div.myTest:contains("'+myVal+'")').length;
```

But this wouldn't work with strings containing double quotes. For any kind of string, I would rather suggest

```
var existingList = $('div.myTest').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf(myVal)>=0;
}).length;
```

To issue the number of found results, use

```
$("#howMany").html(existingList);
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to use indexOf because it is buggy with ie8

Comment: Are you sure you're not confused with the indexOf of arrays (which is missing on IE8) ? I never read that indexOf of strings is known to be buggy on IE8.

Comment: This ended up working too:   var existingList = $('div.myTest:contains(&quot;"+myVal+"&quot;)').length;